# ANTLR reg. expression error

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr3

Can you see any error with the following regular expression? I am defining it in Antlr 3.4, but it accepts arguments like $one, £one although it shouldn't. However, it doesn't accept o£ne, or o$ne.

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|' _ ') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
  ;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `ID` does not match `"$one"` or `"£one"` as you can see:

#### T.g

```java
grammar T;

parse : ID EOF;
ID    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
```

#### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("$one"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

#### Run the test

```
java -cp antlr-3.4-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
javac -cp antlr-3.4-complete.jar *.java
java -cp .;antlr-3.4-complete.jar Main
```

will produce the following error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched character '$' expecting set null
```

Note that both `antlr-3.4-complete.jar` and `antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar` produce the  same error (or any other 3.x version, for that matter).

My guess is that you're using ANTLRWorks and you didn't notice the error messages on the console tab (they're there!).

Comment: You saved my day. I was just checking the parse tree.